# SIGABRT error puzzling me

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am VERY new to objective-C. My only previous programming experience is with visual BASIC. So yes, i am a noob. But i am fairly intuitive and good with these sorts of things, so i am determined to learn. I decided after learning some basic to create a calculator program from scratch without looking at how to do it, and learn from the experience. I got it up to addition, and it worked beautifully. However, after i added subtraction and multiplication. it, to be blunt, took a shit. Immediately after running, it crashes and brings me to my untouched main.m file with the SIGABRT error. I have no idea what went wrong. the code looks like it should work to me, despite some organizational errors. So i tried commenting out everything i added, but to no avail. It still gives me the error. Any help would be appreciated thank you. Below are pictures of my code:

.h file:
http://i73.photobucket.com/albums/i206/strbarrytree/ScreenShot2011-07-21at42338AM.png

.m file:
http://i73.photobucket.com/albums/i206/strbarrytree/mycode.jpg

Comment: Post the exception (what appears in the console window) after the crash... not all of it, just the first bit (before it starts talking about stacks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably connected an outlet or action in IB and then you deleted the outlet/action in your header file. Check in IB if you have any connection with "!" next to it and delete it.

Comment: Thank you! that was it. Forgot i accidentally created an outlet instead of an action. I just removed the code thinking nothing of it. But look over the references of my buttons it was still trying to connect to nothing. removed it and all is well. thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Please accept the answer (click on the tick next to the answer).